# SocketIoClientDotNet return error "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: c#, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to using c# console to establish a connection with my socket.io on the server side and I am using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet. I have no idea why whenever the program run the

> var cSocket = IO.Socket(websocket);

It return error

> "An item with the same key has already been added"

```
Socket2("ws://eng.testsoc.com/socket.io/?md=" + myid + "&en=&id=1&rd=&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=" + sid);

public static void Socket2(string websocket)
{
     try
        {
            var options = new IO.Options() { IgnoreServerCertificateValidation = true, AutoConnect = true, ForceNew = true };
            var cSocket = IO.Socket(websocket); //Hit Error An item with the same key has already been added 
            cSocket.Connect();

            cSocket.On(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("success");
            });

            cSocket.On(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, () =>
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

 }
```

my question is why will return this error and is my way of calling the socket is in-correct

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As I have noticed, this library omits standard WebSocket URI and instead of

```
Socket soc = new Socket("ws://172.16.0.9:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket");
```

I just passed and it worked:

```
Socket soc = new Socket("http://172.16.0.9:3000");
```